# How do you make a SQL table reflect vertical records in a horizontal fashion

Tags: sql, duplicates, left-join

I have two tables, one has sales records and one has deduct records. There is a primary key that links the two tables called Sales_ID but there are multiple deduct records that belong to one sales record. I am trying to get the sales information and the deduct information on one line. See below for tables and the desired result.

Sales Table:

[image: sales table]

Deducts table:

[image: deducts table]

Desired results:
[image: desired product]

```
SELECT SALES.SALES_ID, SALES.SALE_QTY, SALES.SALE_AMT
FROM SALES 
LEFT JOIN DEDUCTS
    ON SALES.SALES_ID = DEDUCTS.SALE_ID
```

I understand that If I add a deduct code in the select statement I will get duplicates, but I don't know what to try to avoid that.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it always just `SEV` and `REG` and only one of each for each `Sales Id`? Or do you expect more than 2 `Deduct Cd-N` columns in your output?

Comment: I expect different deduct codes, probably around 7 or 8 total.